# I am uploading ios app from flutter and error is "Invalid Provisioning profile" , how I can I fix it?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, app-store, app-store-connect, onesignal

Asset validation failed (90161)
Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle uz.blackandwhite.courier.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension [Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal. (ID: c864df39-9369-49f4-bc76-b46165b032ba)

I recreated onesignal and it did not worked,